# Uncaught ReferenceError: deleted1 is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hei, can someone help me? I've tried to delete one of the row and the error below came out when I have already declare the button.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: deleted1 is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Is it because of the script type is module? Can someone please help me?

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
              <th style="width: 14%;">Email</th>
              <th style="width: 23%;">Address</th>
              <th style="width: 16%;">Brought</th>
              <th style="width: 5%;">Quantity</th>
              <th style="width: 5%;">Status</th>
              <th>Options</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tbody1">
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Plant Record</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <label class="labs">Email: </label>
                <input type="text" disabled id="CategoryMod"><br>
                <label class="labs">Item Brought: </label>
                <input type="text" disabled id="ImageMod"><br>
                <label class="labs">Quantity: </label>
                <input type="text" disabled id="NameMod"><br>
                <label class="labs">Address: </label>
                <input type="text" disabled id="PriceMod"><br>
                <label class="labs">Address Code: </label>
                <input type="text" disabled id="StockMod"><br>
                <label class="labs">Status: </label>
                <select class="status" id="inputStatus">
                  <option selected>Choose...</option>
                  <option value="1">Prepared</option>
                  <option value="2">Delivered</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            <button id="saveModeBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="'+savePlant()+'">Save Update</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="module">
    // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
    import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.2/firebase-app.js";
    import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.2/firebase-analytics.js";
    import { getFirestore, doc, setDoc, collection, addDoc, getDocs, onSnapshot, query, where, orderBy, limit } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.2/firebase-firestore.js";
    // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries
  
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: *******,
      authDomain: ******,
      databaseURL: *******",
      projectId: "*******",
      storageBucket: "*******",
      messagingSenderId: "********",
      appId: "*********",
      measurementId: "*****"
    };
  
    // Initialize Firebase
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
    const firestore = getFirestore();
        
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(firestore, "ordered"), orderBy("broughtAt"));
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                let id = doc.id
                let data = doc.data()

                const list = document.getElementById("tbody1");
                const row = document.createElement("tr");

                row.innerHTML += `               
                    <td class="grid-item">${(data.paidby)}</td>
                    <td class="grid-item">No. ${(data.numbur)}, Simpang ${(data.spg)}, Jalan ${(data.jln)}, ${(data.district)}, ${(data.code)}</td>
                    <td class="grid-item">'${(data.product)}'</td>
                    <td class="grid-item">${(data.amount)}</td>
                    <td class="grid-item">${(data.status)}</td>
                    <td class="grid-item"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">Update Status</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-primary my-2 ml-2" onclick="deleted1('${id}')">Delete</button></td>
                    `;

                    list.appendChild(row);

                    async function deleted1(id){
                        await deleteDoc(doc(firestore, "ordered", id));
                    }
            });
      </script>
```

Comment: Where is the function `deleted1` defined?

Comment: Incidentally a `label` element should be associated with an `input` element - either by using `for="<ID>"` where `<ID>` is the id of the input element or by encasing the input within the open/closing tags

Comment: deleted1 is in the javascript, on the bottom line of the row.innerHTML

Comment: I can see that the function `deleted1` is written in the string of HTML - my question was where is it defined? I cannot see the function here and have no idea what it does.

Comment: Incidentally `onclick="'+savePlant()+'">` is incorrect. You do not need to escape from the HTML before adding that function/event handler - simply `onclick="savePlant()">` or better still use external event listeners using `element.addEventListener('click',savePlant)` etc

Comment: ohh, I see. I did forgot to define the button but will that be needed tho, eventho I have used the `onclick` function?

Comment: The `button` **IS** defined but the function called in the `onclick` is not.  That is the reason you are getting `deleted1 is not defined` as an error.

Comment: I think I need to get my eyes tested. Looking again now I can see, as you so correctly stated, that the `deleted1` function was at the bottom but should note that it is declared within a loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is actually correct for this situation having no experience of Firebase but the `deleted1` function should only be declared a single time with new values passed in at runtime. As there seems to be a reliance upon a variable `doc` within the function body and as that is declared within the `querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {` construct one means to supply that to the function is as an argument - the name is not dependent on the name of the actual variable passed in so I called it `obj`. The `inline` event handler that you had initially can likely be replaced with an external event listener applied after all the HTML has been append to the document.

```
// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
const firestore = getFirestore();


async function deleted1( obj, id ){
    await deleteDoc( obj( firestore, "ordered", id ) );
};
    
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(firestore, "ordered"), orderBy("broughtAt"));
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        let id = doc.id;
        let data = doc.data();

        const list = document.getElementById("tbody1");
        const row = document.createElement("tr");

        row.innerHTML += `               
            <td class="grid-item">${(data.paidby)}</td>
            <td class="grid-item">No. ${(data.numbur)}, Simpang ${(data.spg)}, Jalan ${(data.jln)}, ${(data.district)}, ${(data.code)}</td>
            <td class="grid-item">'${(data.product)}'</td>
            <td class="grid-item">${(data.amount)}</td>
            <td class="grid-item">${(data.status)}</td>
            <td class="grid-item">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">Update Status</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-primary my-2 ml-2" data-id="${id}">Delete</button>
            </td>
            `;

            list.appendChild(row);
    });
    
    document.querySelectorAll('td > button.btn').forEach(bttn=>{
        bttn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
            console.log( doc, this.dataset.id )
            deleted1( doc, this.dataset.id )
        };
    })
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This really worked and helps me alot